# Rails getter and setter method issue?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4.1, ruby-2.1

inside user.rb model

```
before_save :update_stripe

def update_stripe
  if customer_id.nil? #line 1
    if !stripe_token.present? #line 2
      raise "Stripe token not present. Can't create account."
    end
    customer = Stripe::Customer.create(
      :email => email, #line 3
      :card => stripe_token, #line 4
    )
    self.role = "owner" #line 5
  end
end
```

when i do 'role = "owner"' it doesn't sets 'role' setter but doing 'self.role = "owner"' sets it, in 'line 5', How ? Also 'customer_id', 'stripe_token', 'email' and 'stripe_token' getter works to get value without 'self' keyword in 'line 1', 'line 2', 'line 3' and 'line 4' resp. How ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Ruby - instance methods: why can i use getter without self, but setter only with self](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19617169/ruby-instance-methods-why-can-i-use-getter-without-self-but-setter-only-with)

Comment: There are a lot of other very similar questions beyond the one I linked to

Comment: thaks Frederick Cheung

Answer (score 1, accepted):

doing setter_method = val, means, you actually create a local variable inside your method and not accessing your setter, as mentioned in the link provided by Frederick Cheung.